# Same theme in WordPress multisites but with custom css?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multisite

How can I apply the same theme on a WordPress multisites but with differents theme options on each site ?

For example :

site1 --> Theme X with red main color

site2 --> Theme X with green main color

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need the same theme for both sites, I really advise you to use [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes):

```
Site 1 - Main theme:
```

- Create **/wp-content/themes/site1**
- Create **/wp-content/themes/site1/style.css:**

  ```
  /*  
  Theme Name: site1
  Template: site1
  Description: Site1 default theme
  Version: 1.0
  Author: <Author_Name>
  Author URI: <Author_URI>
  */
  ```
- Add the rest of the required template files

Then linking the main theme styles and adding your custom class when creating the child theme as following:

```
Site 2 - Child theme:
```

- Create **/wp-content/themes/site1-child**
- Now add all the files you need to override in your child theme in **/wp-content/themes/site1-child/**
- Create **/wp-content/themes/site1-child/style.css:**

  ```
   /*  
      Theme Name: site1 child
      Template: site
      Description: Site1 child theme
      Author: <Author_Name>
      Author URI: <Author_URI>
      */
  ```
- Add this on the top of your **/wp-content/themes/site1-child/style.css** (below the commented theme info) file to include the styles of your main theme within the child:

  `@import url("../site1/style.css");`
- Add your custom styles below the `@import` as desired

`Sites configuration:`

After creating the sites in the network panel (**/wp-admin/network/sites.php**), go to each site's `dashboard`:

- **/wp-admin/** for the main site
- **/sitename/wp-admin** for the second site

Within the **theme** section, make sure to assign:

- your main site to **site1** theme
- your second site to **site1-child** theme

I hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Hello Marounm,
Thank you very much.
So I have to configure the site 1 in first, and then copy the css options to customize there on the child theme.
This process seems to be clear.
Than you, I'll try that :)

Comment: Actually the child class is unnecessary, all styles added in the style.css file in your -child theme will only affect site 2 anyway. I updated my answer make sure to follow accordingly. Now regarding what you said, yes you'll have to configure site1 first as the main website after assigning site1 theme to it, then create site2 and assign site1-child theme accordingly as discussed in my answer also please make sure to accept this question if that fixed your issue :)

Comment: You shouldn't use @import on the css file. It's better practice creating a functions.php file in your child theme and import the child theme there

Comment: @catmal I'm using import in order to copy the main css file into the child css, I need it to load exactly in this file that's why I didn't use the enqueue function in the child theme's functions.php. Anyway that's no major issue for the main child theme css, you can always import other css/scripts (related to additional loaded libraries) the proper way by overriding function.php in the child-theme folder and adding your enqueue function to it.

Comment: You achieve the same if you remove import from your child theme css file,  create a functions.php and add the code as shown here https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 2):

Although child site option is a good solution. I had a situation where I only wanted to change a few CSS styles! So I opted to do the following.

In the theme header I got the ID of the Site with

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
```

Then in the body tag added the id with

```
<body id="site-id-<?php echo $blog_id; ?>" <?php body_class(); ?> >
```

This then outputted the html like this:

```
<body id="site-id-3" class="page-template-default page page-id-8 logged-in admin-bar customize-support">
```

So now in my LESS / SASS etc I can add custom styling like the following:

```
#site-id-3 p { color: red; }
```

Hope this helps